# How many bits does $realtime return in Verilog and Systemverilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

How many bits does *$realtime* return in Verilog and *Systemverilog*?

Answer (score 2):

`$realtime` does not return bits, it returns an double precision floating point number, which has requires 1 bit for the sign, 11 bits for the exponent, and 52-bits for the mantissa. You cannot access individual bits of a real number, so the total number of bits is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

From sutherland hdl quick ref. Pg 40 in the doc, 44 in your pdf viewer

http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/pdfs/verilog_2001_ref_guide.pdf

> $time
>
> $stime
>
> $realtime
>
> Returns the current simulation time as a 64-bit vector, a
> 32-bit integer or a real number, respectively.

The value returned will depend on your `timescale`. i.e. if timescale is 1ns/1ps, and you have ran for 1us, you will return 1,000.000.